# Rsync: Escape include/exclude wildcards

Tags: wildcard, rsync

I am running `rsync --include-from=my_includes_file --exclude="*" source dest`, and building the include file from a big find command (similar to `find documents/* -newer ~/.lasttime`). However, many of my filenames include the "wildcard" characters used by rsync (`*`, `?`, `[`, `]`), and occasionally I have a problem with the include comment character too (`#`).

1. Is there a universal way to escape these? Using `\[` seems to fix this one, but I'm not sure if it works for all of them or if I'm just getting lucky
2. Is there an include prefix to force a "simple string match"?

Answer (score -1):

You are using

```
 --include-from=FILE     read include patterns from FILE
```

While you should use

```
 --files-from=FILE       read list of source-file names from FILE
```